# Error while reading JSON file in chunksizes with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compiler-errors

I have a large json file, so I want to read the file in chunks while testing. I have implemented the code below:

```
if fpath.endswith('.json'):
    with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
        read_query = pd.read_json(f, lines=True, chunksize=100)
        
        for chunk in read_query:
            print(chunk)
```

I get the error:

```
 File "nameoffile.py", line 168, in read_queries_func
    for chunk in read_query:
  File "C:\Users\Me\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 798, in __next__
    obj = self._get_object_parser(lines_json)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 770, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "C:\Users\Me\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 885, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "C:\Users\Me\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 1159, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Why am I getting an error?

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "a": "13", 
    "b": "55"
  }, 
  {
    "a": "15", 
    "b": "16"
  }, 
  {
    "a": "18", 
    "b": "45"
  }, 

  {
    "a": "1650", 
    "b": "26"
  }, 
       .
       .
       .
  {
    "a": "214", 
    "b": "23"
  }
]
```

Also, is there a way to extract just the 'a' attribute's values while reading the file? Or can that only be done after I've read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file contains just one object. As per the [line-delimited json doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#line-delimited-json) to which [the doc of the `chunksize` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) points:

> pandas is able to read and write line-delimited json files that are common in data processing pipelines using Hadoop or Spark.
>
> For line-delimited json files, pandas can also return an iterator which reads in chunksize lines at a time. This can be useful for large files or to read from a stream.

It also implies that `lines=True`, and the doc for lines says:

> Read the file as a json object per line.

This means that files like this work:

```json
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
{"a": 3, "b": 4}
{"a": 5, "b": 6}
{"a": 7, "b": 8}
{"a": 9, "b": 10}
```

These don’t:

```
[
{"a": 1, "b": 2},
{"a": 3, "b": 4},
{"a": 5, "b": 6},
{"a": 7, "b": 8},
{"a": 9, "b": 10}
]
```

So you have to read the file in one go, or modify it as you go to have one object per line.